# iOS UISearchController doesn't span fully

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

In some device types mostly in 6s, the `UISearchController` doesn't span fully.

```
    //Init search controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    searchBar.frame = self.searchBarHolder.bounds;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate= self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate=self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    [self.searchBarHolder addSubview:searchBar];
    [self.searchBarHolder layoutIfNeeded];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
```

where `searchBarHolder` is set in storyboard with constraints `trailing-0, top-0, leading-0, height - 45`

This produces the following result :

[image]

and once the search bar is clicked it will `becomeFirstResponder` and there after, it displays properly.

[image]

I have no clue why it displays like that at first place.

This `UIViewController` is embedded in `UINavigationCOntroller`, and this is embedded in `UITabBarController` as one of the tab item.

Comment: does the "cancel" button ever appear?

Comment: Yes, it appears when the search bar is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this Line

```
searchBar.frame = self.searchBarHolder.bounds;
```

With this

```
CGRect rect = self.searchBarHolder.bounds;
rect.size.width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
searchBar.frame = rect
```